Can I get a histogram where each value is the sum instead of count of values in bucket?
I have a dataset with the elapsed time of certain events and I would like to know the total time spent in each time bracket using polars.
The hist function gives the count of events within each bracket like this:
>>> df = pl.DataFrame(
...     {
...         "nam": ["a", "a", "a", "b", "b", "b", "b"],
...         "ela": [1, 1, 20, 3, 4, 10, 20],
...     }
... )
>>> df.group_by("nam").agg(
...     pl.col("ela").hist([ 1, 10,])
... )
shape: (2, 2)
┌─────┬───────────┐
│ nam ┆ ela       │
│ --- ┆ ---       │
│ str ┆ list[u32] │
╞═════╪═══════════╡
│ a   ┆ [2, 0, 1] │
│ b   ┆ [0, 3, 1] │
└─────┴───────────┘



What I would like to see is something like this
shape: (2, 2)
┌─────┬─────────────┐
│ nam ┆ ela         │
│ --- ┆ ---         │
│ str ┆ list[u32]   │
╞═════╪═════════════╡
│ a   ┆ [2, 0, 20]  │
│ b   ┆ [0, 17, 20] │
└─────┴─────────────┘

I've tried to use cut and implode
>>> (df.with_columns(pl.col("ela").cut([ 1, 10,]).alias("bucket"))
...     .group_by("nam", "bucket")
...     .agg(ela=pl.sum("ela"))
...     .group_by("nam")
...     .agg(pl.sum("ela").alias("ela_sum"), pl.implode("bucket", "ela"))
... )
shape: (2, 4)
┌─────┬─────────┬──────────────────────────────┬─────────────────┐
│ nam ┆ ela_sum ┆ bucket                       ┆ ela             │
│ --- ┆ ---     ┆ ---                          ┆ ---             │
│ str ┆ i64     ┆ list[list[cat]]              ┆ list[list[i64]] │
╞═════╪═════════╪══════════════════════════════╪═════════════════╡
│ b   ┆ 37      ┆ [["(1, 10]", "(10, inf]"]]   ┆ [[17, 20]]      │
│ a   ┆ 22      ┆ [["(-inf, 1]", "(10, inf]"]] ┆ [[2, 20]]       │
└─────┴─────────┴──────────────────────────────┴─────────────────┘

but I don't know how to get the compact inclusive format that hist. It is missing the zero buckets and for some reason it shows up as a list within list.

Please remember that Stack Overflow is not your favourite Python forum, but rather a question and answer site for all programming related questions. Thus, always include the tag of the language you are programming in, that way other users familiar with that language can more easily find your question. Take the [tour] and read up on [ask] to get more information on how this site works, then [edit] the question with the relevant tags.

Are you trying to do this for a "single interval"? e.g. every 10? It looks like it could be a group_by_dynamic type problem instead if that was the case.

RE: list within a list - Polars by default will aggregate into a list, you can just use pl.col("bucket", "ela"). By using implode you introduce another level of nesting.

Maybe not really elegant, but you could do something like:
df_res = df.with_columns(bucket = pl.col.ela.cut([ 1, 10,]).to_physical())

(
    pl.DataFrame(pl.Series("bucket", range(3), dtype=pl.UInt32))
    .join(df.select(pl.col.nam.unique()), how="cross")
    .join(df_res, on=["bucket","nam"], how="left")
    .group_by("nam","bucket").sum()
    .sort("nam","bucket")
    .group_by("nam", maintain_order=True).agg(pl.col.ela)
)

shape: (2, 2)
┌─────┬─────────────┐
│ nam ┆ ela         │
│ --- ┆ ---         │
│ str ┆ list[i64]   │
╞═════╪═════════════╡
│ a   ┆ [2, 0, 20]  │
│ b   ┆ [0, 17, 20] │
└─────┴─────────────┘


There is a slight problem with this, that I can't figure out, The 'b' values 3,4 and 10 should all go into the second bucket like [0, 17, 20 ]. And actually when I run it on my machine I get the buckets in a different order a: [20, 2  0] , b: [20, 0, 17].

of course, I've changed the answer. I think we need to sort the intermediate results and keep the order during grouping

Solution
Here's one ugly way to do it, I sure hope there are better ways:
import polars as pl
import polars.selectors as cs

df = pl.DataFrame(
    {
        "nam": ["a", "a", "a", "b", "b", "b", "b"],
        "ela": [1, 1, 20, 3, 4, 10, 20],
    }
)


(
    df.with_columns(pl.col("ela").cut([1, 10,]).alias("bucket"))
    .group_by("nam", "bucket")
    .agg(
        b=pl.col("ela").hist([1, 10,]),
        c=pl.col("ela").sum()
    )
    .select(
        (
            pl.col("b").list.eval(
                pl.element() > 0
            ) * pl.col("c")
        ).list.to_struct(),
        pl.col("nam")
    )
    .unnest("b")
    .group_by("nam")
    .agg(pl.concat_list(cs.numeric().sum()).alias("bucket"))
)

This gives you the result of:
┌─────┬─────────────┐
│ nam ┆ bucket      │
│ --- ┆ ---         │
│ str ┆ list[i64]   │
╞═════╪═════════════╡
│ a   ┆ [2, 0, 20]  │
│ b   ┆ [0, 17, 20] │
└─────┴─────────────┘

Explanation
Breaking it down a bit, combining your two attempts to one that we can use:
df.with_columns(pl.col("ela").cut([1, 10,]).alias("bucket"))
    .group_by("nam", "bucket")
    .agg(
        b=pl.col("ela").hist([1, 10,]),
        c=pl.col("ela").sum()
)
┌─────┬───────────┬───────────┬─────┐
│ nam ┆ bucket    ┆ b         ┆ c   │
│ --- ┆ ---       ┆ ---       ┆ --- │
│ str ┆ cat       ┆ list[u32] ┆ i64 │
╞═════╪═══════════╪═══════════╪═════╡
│ b   ┆ (10, inf] ┆ [0, 0, 1] ┆ 20  │
│ a   ┆ (-inf, 1] ┆ [2, 0, 0] ┆ 2   │
│ a   ┆ (10, inf] ┆ [0, 0, 1] ┆ 20  │
│ b   ┆ (1, 10]   ┆ [0, 3, 0] ┆ 17  │
└─────┴───────────┴───────────┴─────┘

And then the rest is an ugly way to transform that to he final result by

Counting the non-zero occurrences in lists
Converting to struct and further unnesting to columns (to get element-wise sum of the lists)
Calculating the groupwise sums and aggregating the lists back with concat_list and numeric selector.


Also not ideal, but it seems it is possible to link the .hist() and .cut() results using the breakpoint.
bins = [1, 10]

hist = (
   df.group_by("nam", maintain_order=True)
     .agg(
        pl.col("ela").hist(bins, include_breakpoint=True)
          .struct.field("breakpoint")
          .alias("breakpoint")
     )
     .explode("breakpoint")
)

cut = (
   df
    .with_columns(
       pl.col("ela").cut(bins, include_breaks=True)
         .over("nam")
         .struct.field("breakpoint")
    )
    .group_by("nam", "breakpoint")
    .sum()
) 

hist.join(cut, on=["nam", "breakpoint"], how="left")

shape: (6, 3)
┌─────┬────────────┬──────┐
│ nam ┆ breakpoint ┆ ela  │
│ --- ┆ ---        ┆ ---  │
│ str ┆ f64        ┆ i64  │
╞═════╪════════════╪══════╡
│ a   ┆ 1.0        ┆ 2    │
│ a   ┆ 10.0       ┆ null │
│ a   ┆ inf        ┆ 20   │
│ b   ┆ 1.0        ┆ null │
│ b   ┆ 10.0       ┆ 17   │
│ b   ┆ inf        ┆ 20   │
└─────┴────────────┴──────┘

